# {{ user.get_profile.foo }} not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display user profile information in the users profile (original, I know,) but I can't get it to work unless it's the form view of the profile.  I call `user` and `foo` in my user profile edit form with `{{form.instance.user}}` and it works fine.

I've implemented `{{ user.get_profile.foo }}` in my static user profile template (`loggedin.html`) but nothing happens.

My static user profile (`loggedin.html`) template looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <title>{% block title %} | {{ username }}{% endblock %}</title>

    <h2>Hi, {{ username }}!</h2>
    <h3>{{ user.get_profile.foo }}</h3>

    <a href="/accounts/profile/">Edit Profile</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

The view for `loggedin.html`:

```
def loggedin(request):
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html', {'username':request.user.username, 'user':request.user})
```

My user profile edit form(`profile.html`) template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <title>{% block title %} | Edit Profile{% endblock %}</title>

    <h2>Edit {{ username }}</h2>

    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.error }}
    {% endfor %}

   <form action="/accounts/profile/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       <label for="id_user">Username:</label>
       <br>
       <input id="id_user" name="user" type="text" value="{{form.instance.user}}">
       <br><br>
       <label for="id_foo">Foo:</label>
       <br>
       <input id="id_foo" name="foo" type="text" value="{{form.instance.foo}}">
       <br><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Update">

   </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

My user profile (form) model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=30)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

My user profile (form) view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from forms import UserProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from userprofile.models import UserProfile

@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    username = request.user.username

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        profile = user.profile
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    args['user'] = user
    args['username'] = username

    return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

I can get the `username` and `foo` value to display fine in the user profile form, but when I try to get the same information to display in the static profile, it doesn't work.

Full disclosure: my static profile is in an app called `polls` which is different than the `userprofile` app where my edit form model and template are located, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this issue.

If you need to see my urls, settings, or admin code, let me know; I figured it wasn't relevant, and would just add clutter, but I'm happy to add it if needed.

Comment: What does `{{ user.foo }}` in your template return?

Comment: You have added a property `User.profile`, but you are trying to access `user.get_profile` in your template.

Comment: I have tried `{{ user.foo }}`, `{{ User.get_profile.foo }}` , `{{ User.foo }}` and none of them return anything.

Comment: If your property is `User.profile`, have you tried `{{ user.profile.foo }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property is `User.profile`. Therefore you should try

```
{{ user.profile.foo }}
```

in your template, instead of `{{ user.get_profile.foo }}`.